# How to create thread scope in autofac DI

Tags: multithreading, autofac

I am new to autofac DI. I have followed the official documentation of autofac scopes from below URL.

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#thread-scope

Here it is mentioned that to create a thread scope the example given was

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<MyThreadScopedComponent>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

var container = builder.Build();
```

How do I create MyThreadScopedComponent class?

Answer (score 0):

In whichever class in which you need to use `MyThreadScopedComponent`, inject it into the constructor like so:

```
public class Test
{
    private MyThreadScopedComponent MyComponent { get; }

    public Test(MyThreadScopedComponent myComponent)
    {
        MyComponent = myComponent;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        MyComponent.DoStuff();
    }
}
```